# SwiftUI Combine validation on form submit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm new for swiftUI and Combine and I want to validate the form on button submit, I don't want to disable the submit button, I just want whenever user tap on the submit button without filling any details, fields should become red with error messages.

**Expected result**

Initial state:[image]

After Submit: [image]

**My code is something like this:**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var firstName = ""
    @Published var isFirstNameValid = true
    
    private var publishers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        
        isFirstNameValidPublisher
        **    .dropFirst()**
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isFirstNameValid, on: self)
            .store(in: &publishers)
    }
}

// MARK: - Setup validations
private extension SignUpViewModel {
    

    var isFirstNameValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $firstName
            .map { firstname in
                return firstname.count > 0
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

**    .dropFirst() **

After using the .dropfirst it not showing the error on the page load(initially) but when I try to change anything in the firstName field and again leave the field empty it display the error.

Is here any way to display the error when user click on the button without touching the fields.

OR

Any way to re-run the isFirstNameValidPublisher on button click, so it can detect the latest.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use combine for this?  You could just write a validation method in your model

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

By trying to use Combine when you don't need to `combineLatest` different async publishers you're just overcomplicating it, try this instead:

```
@State var firstName = ""
@State var isValid = true
```

```
Button("Sign Up") {
    isValid = firstName.count > 0
}
.disabled(!isValid)
```

Comment: thank for the answer but I don't want to disable the button, button will alway be active. I want to behave my validation like these.  


   1. If user focus on any textfield and leave without filling it, then error should display for that particular field. (like required message) 

   2. If user filled invalid values like email or password, then error should display for that particular field. (like Invalid message)

   3. If user click on submit button then error should display for all fields which are empty. (like required message)

   4. Submit button should always be active.

Comment: please edit your question, you said you did want to disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have error processing linked to your submit button, we can create states with the SwiftUI `@State` property wrapper, allowing us to access each input, such as the following set:

- `@State var firstName = ""`
- `@State var lastName = ""`
- `@State var emailAddress = ""`

We can then bind them to TextField controls like the following:

- `TextField("Firstname", text: $firstName)`
- `TextField("Lastname", text: $lastName)`
- `TextField("Email", text: $emailAddress)`

For the presentation of errors, we can have some color states like:

- `@State var firstNameErrorColor: Color? = .clear`
- `@State var lastNameErrorColor: Color? = .clear`
- `@State var emailErrorColor: Color? = .clear`

Finally, for the button action, we can evaluate all error conditions based on the bound states and display an error by setting a new color to make them visible, like in the following code:

```
Button("Sign Up") {
    if nameIsValid(name: name) {
        color = .red
    } 
        color = .clear
    }
}
```

We can save using Publishers for more complex tasks, as suggested by others, and leverage SwiftUI's state-observing capabilities in this example.